# Need help Mixing Video and Text and save into another file

Tags: c#, directshow, video-capture

I need to add text, image over video and save mixed file into another new video file.I know about DirectShow but will allow to play video with text but i am not sure how i can save this mixed video for future use.Please help.

Thanks,
Firoz Khan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are DirectShow filters for video compression and writing to files. I don't know if this is directly available in .NET, but it's pretty easy in C++. You simply remove rendering filter, and put there compression filer --> multiplexing filter --> file writer filter.

You can try it in GraphEdit. You can also find useful C++ source code examples in DirectShow SDK.